# R countif and sum on multiple columns matching elements in specified vector

Tags: r, countif

I am applying this function to my dataset column DL1 on another vector as below and receiving the results expected

```
table(df$DL1[df$DL1 %in% undefined_dl_codes])
```

Result:

```
0  10  30  3B   4  49  54  5A  60   7  78   8  90 

24 366   4   3 665  40   1   1  14   8   4  87   1
```

however I do have columns DL2, DL3 and DL4 which have same data, how can I apply the function to multiple columns and receive the result of all. I would need to go through all 4 required columns and receive 1 result as summary.

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be the best of the methods, however you could do the following

```
    table(c(df$DL1[df$DL1 %in% undefined_dl_codes],
    df$DL2[df$DL2 %in% undefined_dl_codes],
    df$DL3[df$DL3 %in% undefined_dl_codes],
    df$DL4[df$DL4 %in% undefined_dl_codes]
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Raghuveer solution I further simplified,

attach(df)

table(c(DL1,DL2,DL3,DL4)[c(DL1,DL2,DL3,DL4) %in% undefined_dl_codes])

detach(df)